# Why NodeList[0] and node = NodeList[0] behave differently?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

In the following code excerpt, products is a xml nodelist, which structure is:

```
<products>
  <product>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>item1</name>
  </product>
  <product>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>item2</name>
  </product>
</products>



xml = httpRequest.responseXML
products = xml.getElementsByTagName('products')


products[0].constructor
//=>ElementConstructor

product = products[0]
//=><product>…</product>

product.constructor
//=>ElementConstructor

product.getElementsByTagName('id')
//[ <id>1</id> ]

for(product in products){product.getElementsByTagName('id')}
//=>TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'product.getElementsByTagName('id')')
```

how can I iterate each `<product>` element in `<products>` element, and select only  tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(product in products)`:

- iterates over all the enumerable properties of the object, not just the ones with numbers for the property name
- gives you the property names, not the values

This code:

```
var products = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
for(product in products) { console.log(product); }
```

Gives:

```
0
length
item
```

If you want to loop over the elements, then you need to use a regular `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    var product = products[i];
    // do something with product
}
```

Comment: So products is an object structure like`{1:product,2:product}`?

Comment: Only in the same sense that an Array is.

Comment: but that's what I got from the console return value:products = xml.getElementsByTagName('product')
[
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
, 
<product>…</product>
]

Comment: Objects can specify how `console.log` renders them. Whoever wrote that function for NodeLists was, presumably, of the opinion that you should know it is a node list and thus do not need a list of all the methods on it.

Comment: but for in loop can be used in array `ary = [1,2,3];for(element in ary){console.log(element)}, #=>1,2,3`

Comment: +1 for saying that object can specify how console.log render them

Comment: @pimvdb that's really strange, I'm using safari 6.0 console. do you think it will behave differently than yours?

Comment: @yozloy — The enumerable properties of an array and the enumerable properties of a NodeList are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your question title doesn't represent the issue. A `NodeList` can be iterated as if it was an array:

```
for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  var product = products[i];
  // ...
}
```

You're doing a `for in` loop. `product` then refers to the keys (i.e. `0`, `1`, ...) instead, which don't have `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer, so products is not an array isn't it?

Comment: @yozloy: It is commonly called an "array-like object" because it has indices and `.length` like an array does. But it doesn't have array functions available on it (like `forEach`).

Comment: wow, good to know that. is there any way that I can inspect whether it's an array-like object or an array, because in the console, the return value of products is [<product>,<product>,<product>],which is array for me

Comment: @yozloy: That's misleading indeed. There is the `Array.isArray` function.

Answer (score 2):

For in iterates over indices. You want

```
products[product].getElementByTagName('id')
```

Comment: +1 for letting me still using `for in` loop to iterate an object